# How to detect if element was faded out

Tags: jquery, if-statement, fadein, fadeout

I want to have two buttons, one to fade div1 out, and one either to fade div1 in, or to fade out the button itself, if the div1 is already hidden. here's the code, pretty unnecessary though, cause my main problem is "if" statement...

```
$('#b > button').click(function(){
    $('#div1').fadeOut(400)
});

$('#div2 > button').click(function(){
    $('#div1').fadeIn(400)
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not to disable/enable the buttons?

```
$('#b > button').click(function(){
    $('#div1').fadeOut(400, function() {
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        $('#div2 > button').prop('disabled', false);
    });
});

$('#div2 > button').click(function(){
    $('#div1').fadeIn(400, function() {
        $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        $('#b > button').prop('disabled', false);
    });
});
```

Comment: This is a much better solution, as the other two suggestions involve reading from the DOM which is completely unnecessary and expensive as far as performance goes. It is much better to maintain state within your code and a simple toggle like this works. Much better to write to the DOM then read from the DOM.

Answer (score 20):

FadeOut simply changes the `display` to `none`.

Check if the display is none using jQuery's `$('selector').css('display')` or `$('selector').is(':visible')`